# I am using HashMap in HashMap but I need to use ArrayList as value as well. I'm having trouble giving value

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am using HashMap in HashMap but I need to use ArrayList as value as well. I'm having trouble giving value

```
private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> languages_hashmap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>();

public void addvalue (String language, String code , String value, boolean isStringArray)
{

    HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> dictionary = languages_hashmap.get(language);
    if (dictionary == null)
    {
        dictionary = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
    }

    dictionary.put(code, value );
    languages_hashmap.put(code, dictionary);

}
```

Comment: well "value" has to be an arraylist.. what do you want to do with the "value" string? do you want to split the string with a certain delimiter and add it to the ArrayList then add to the dictionary? if not then what?

Comment: Your code is not compilable. `dictionary.put(code, value );` Requires ArrayList<String>, and you are passing String.

Comment: Why not create a bean instead of nesting maps?  This will be tough to understand for the next person reading your code.

Comment: People over here need clear understanding of your issue, by looking at your code its really hard to understand what is a issue your having in the code, please share log or error details with your code.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need objects in your life, nesting so many maps and collections is a code smell.

There are two different concepts in your code :

- A `Dictionary` holds `values` for each `code`
- Another thing that associates a `Dictionary` to a language. I'll call it `Translator`, but you should probably find a name more suitable

Separating responsibilities will make your code more readable, and allow you to test each case separately :

```
public class Translator {

    // Reference interface instead of concrete types whenever you can
    // (i.e. use Map instead of HashMap)
    private Map<String, Dictionary> dictionaries = new HashMap<>();

    public void addValue(String lang, String code, String value) {
        dictionaries.get(lang).add(code, value);
    }

    public List<String> getValue(String lang, String code) {
        return dictionaries.get(lang).get(code);
    }

    public void addDictionary(String lang, Dictionary dictionary) {
        dictionaries.put(lang, dictionary);
    }

}


public class Dictionary {

    // Same here, use interfaces like List or Map instead of their implementations
    Map<String, List<String>> values = new HashMap<>();

    public void add(String code, String value) {
        List<String> list = values.get(code);
        // if there is no previous value for this code, 
        // create a new list of values
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            values.put(code, list);
        }
        list.add(value);
    }

    public List<String> get(String code) {
        return values.get(code);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addvalue (String language, String code , String value, boolean isStringArray)
{

HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> dictionary = languages_hashmap.get(language);
if (dictionary == null)
{
    dictionary = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
    languages_hashmap.put(code, dictionary);
}

List<String> list = dictionary.get(code);
if (list == null) {
   list = new ArrayList<>();
   dictionary.put(code, list);
}
list.add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not compilable. `dictionary.put(code, value );`

Requires `ArrayList<String>`, and you are passing `String`.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(value);
dictionary.put (code, list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Type of **value** parameter is String, it should be ArrayList< String> as dictionary variable is a type of  HashMap< String,ArrayList> dictionary

```
    dictionary.put (code, value);
```

where  **code** is String and  **value** should be of the type ArrayList

```
public void addvalue (String language, String code , ArrayList<String> value, boolean isStringArray)
```

if you want to pass value as String parameter to addvalue function then create ArrayList< String> in function and add value to it and then pass to dictionary.

```
     private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>languages_hashmap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, 
     ArrayList<String>>>();

     ArrayList<String> tempValue=new ArrayList<>();

    public void addvalue (String language, String code , String value, 
    boolean isStringArray)
       {
         tempValue.add("value");
         HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> dictionary = languages_hashmap.get(language);

      if (dictionary == null)
      {
          dictionary = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
      }

      dictionary.put(code,  tempValue );
      languages_hashmap.put(code, dictionary);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, you can't pass String to ArrayList

either change the type of value to ArrayList in method signature

```
private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> languages_hashmap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>();

public void addvalue(String language, String code , ArrayList<String> value, boolean isStringArray)
{

    HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> dictionary = languages_hashmap.get(language);
    if (dictionary == null)
    {
        dictionary = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
    }

    dictionary.put(code, value);
    languages_hashmap.put(code, dictionary);

}
```

or else pass ArrayList of String to it.

Comment: Someone available at the moment can email me                                             e-mail = alkolluyuz345@hotmail.com